# Laravel session variable not set when inside if-statement that is truthy

Tags: laravel, session, session-variables

I have this controller function to flash input to the session, in order to retrieve it later when revisiting the page.

```
public function index(Request $request)
{   
    if ($request->has('email_login')) {

        // $request->flashOnly(['email_login']); // I want to use this, but doesn't work either

        session(['test' => $request->email_login]); // This DOES NOT get stored in the session

        session(['test3' => 'C']); // This DOES NOT get stored in the session

        echo  'yes we come here'; // This DOES output
    }

    session(['test2' => 'B']); // This DOES get flashed to the session
}
```

### Q&A

**Is your if-condition correct?**

*Yes I'm 99,9% sure because both xdebug step through the if-body and the echo works (which it would not when it was not truthy)*

**Does your session get started?**

*Yes I believe so because otherwhise `test2` would not be set either*

**Is it an ajax request?**

*No, but as I set this variable server-sided it should not matter at all (but there are people who believe it does matter)*

So my session only contains `test2`

Comment: When you do `session(['test2' => 'B']);` at the end, the others sessions get overriden. Thats wahy it seems like the is no session

Comment: Your codes above actually works for me.
Test: http://prntscr.com/iirw5e  
Results: http://prntscr.com/iirvvz

Comment: It probably has something to do with some later code then, because I really wouldn't ask if it did work for me haha. But thank you for verifying.

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz you do not override other variables that way as far as I know. It just gets added.

Answer (score 0):

> This is not a good answer, but it solves my problem. This is why I
>   post it. I won't accept it because an **explaination** would be even
>   better.

I found a solution on [this page](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/3061) however I still don't understand why this happens on this request.

I now call `save()` manually on the session object. Something I did not have to do before.

```
public function index(Request $request)
{   
    if ($request->has('email_login')) {

        $request->flashOnly(['email_login']); 
        session()->save();
    }
}
```